# Where is Oracle iPlanet Web Server download page now?

Tags: oracle, webserver

I just trying to setup Loadbalancer of Glassfish 3.1.1, and I follow the following Docs & Videos :

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aK1EebrBWk4&feature=player_embedded (Look @ 5:12)
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2432/gkybx.html#gkydh

But I can't find iPlanet anymore in download page of Oracle !!

Where that iPlanet went?

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lots and lots of searching, i found it here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/webtier/downloads/iplanet-webserver-525365.html

Comment: Nothing can download for iPlanet products in the link above. You can search and download for iPlanet products here: http://edelivery.oracle.com/ with a free account.

Answer (score 2):

iPlanet is not available anymore for public download, u have to have a oracle paid ID - CSI (Customer Support Identifier)  for the download - information from Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

http://edelivery.oracle.com/
-> After login with a free account you can search download for iPlanet products.

Answer (score 0):

It's decommissioned.

> To obtain a Oracle iPlanet Web Proxy Server Installer, login to My
>   Oracle Support and search for the applicable Patch ID below:
>
> - Windows: Patch ID 145607-02
> - Solaris Sparc: Patch ID 145604-02
> - Solaris x86: Patch ID 145606-02
> - Linux: Patch ID 145605-02
> - HP-UX: Patch ID 145608-02

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/webtier/downloads/iplanetwebproxydownload-334721.html

Comment: How?
If you visit : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/webtier/downloads/index.html you can see the link! also http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/iplanetwebserver-098726.html

Comment: I don't understand what the problem of broken links, and why you able to choose iPlanet from LB Plugin 3.1.1 if it decommissioned!, what is the alternative?
Proxy?